# Custom UIImageView works in iOS simulator but is black on iPad when using animated segue

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I've designed a custom UIImageView class that displays a tile pattern. The class is designed to be used in a storyboard. The pattern is built using runtime parameters on a CALayer in the awakeFromNib protocol.

Everything works fine until I try to use an animated segue. It works perfectly on the simulator but when I run it on the iPad, the layer is black. If I disable the animation everything works.

Any ideas?

Here is the code:

_hasRoundedCorners and _textureImage are runtime parameters

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    CALayer *textureLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [textureLayer setFrame:[self bounds]];
    if (_hasRoundedCorners) {
        [textureLayer setCornerRadius:6.0f];
    }
    UIColor *mycolor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_textureImage]];
    [textureLayer setBackgroundColor:mycolor.CGColor];
    [[self layer] addSublayer:textureLayer];
    }
 }
```

UPDATE:
I did further testing. Only some segue animations cause the problem. Cover Vertical and Cross Dissolve exhibit the behavior. Flip Horizontal and Partial Curl work fine.

I also have added additional functionality (see below). The class now will display a gradient or a pattern as well as having an optional drop shadow. Property values are set at design time in the storyboard.

```
@property (assign) BOOL hasDropShadow;
@property (assign) BOOL hasRoundedCorners;
@property (assign) BOOL hasGradient;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *highColor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *lowColor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *textureImage;
```

---

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    //turning off bounds clipping allows the shadow to extend beyond the rect of the view
    if (_hasDropShadow) {
        [self setClipsToBounds:NO];
    }
    CALayer * roundRect = [CALayer layer];
    [roundRect setFrame:[self bounds]];
    if (_hasRoundedCorners) {
        [roundRect setCornerRadius:6.0f];
        [roundRect setMasksToBounds:YES];
    }
    if(_hasGradient){
        //the default colors for the gradient.  highColor is at the top, lowColor as at the bottom
        if (!_highColor){
            _highColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }
        if (!_lowColor){
            _lowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        }
        CAGradientLayer * gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        [gradient setFrame:[self bounds]];
        [gradient setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[_highColor CGColor], (id)[_lowColor CGColor], nil]];
        [roundRect addSublayer:gradient];
    }

    //add the rounded rect layer underneath all other layers of the view
    [[self layer] insertSublayer:roundRect atIndex:0];

    //set the shadow on the view's layer
    if (_hasDropShadow) {
        [[self layer] setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [[self layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 6)];
        [[self layer] setShadowOpacity:1.0];
        [[self layer] setShadowRadius:10.0];
    }
    if(!_hasGradient){
        //set up the texture layer
        CALayer *textureLayer = [CALayer layer];
        [textureLayer setFrame:[self bounds]];
        if (_hasRoundedCorners) {
            [textureLayer setCornerRadius:6.0f];
        }
        UIColor *mycolor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_textureImage]];
        if (mycolor) {
            [textureLayer setBackgroundColor:mycolor.CGColor];
            [[self layer] addSublayer:textureLayer];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got any code to share or should we take a guess?

Comment: Have you tried to put the code into `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: @dasdom Code belongs in the class, not the view controller.

Comment: Check image names to make sure that the case of each letter is correct. iOS is case sensitive unlike the simulator that runs on Mac OS X.